# Ordinal logistic regression in R - p value interpretation

Tags: r, regression, logistic, ordinal-data

I want to know if a certain protein can be a marker of a particular disease and I'm searching for a dose response.
I've created a toy example with three ordered groups: control, sick and very sick.
Although I purposely create a protein which doesn't follow a dose reponse, with clearly no overlap between groups, the ordinal logistic regression model outputs a significant coefficient for protein.

- Why?
- Which model could I use to only get true dose response, negative or positive?
  Thank you.

```
library(ordinal)
library(ggplot2)

d=data.frame(
  group=rep(c('control','sick','very_sick'),times=c(205,205,205)),
  protein=c(rnorm(205, mean=10, sd=1), rnorm(205, mean=-5, sd=1), rnorm(205, mean=5, sd=1)))
 
d$group<- factor(d$group,levels = c('control','sick','very_sick'), ordered = TRUE)  
 

ggplot(d, aes(x=group, y=protein)) + 
  geom_boxplot()

model=clm(group ~ protein, data=d, link='logit')

summary(model)
```

[image]

```
## formula: group ~ protein
## data:    d
## 
##  link  threshold nobs logLik  AIC     niter max.grad cond.H 
##  logit flexible  615  -646.06 1298.12 4(0)  1.12e-11 1.0e+02
## 
## Coefficients:
##         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## protein -0.08753    0.01152  -7.596 3.07e-14 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Threshold coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error z value
## control|low -0.87181    0.09318  -9.356
## low|high     0.62542    0.08807   7.102
```

Comment: It is likely your three sets of protein numbers have "perfect separation" (your no overlap between groups).  Logistic regression often does not handle this well.

Comment: It's just a matter of a) You are switching the *x* and *y* axes on the plot.  Try: `plot(as.numeric(group) ~ protein, data=d)`.  And b) Your sample size is relatively large.  Compare: `summary(lm(as.numeric(group) ~ protein, data=d))`

Comment: So, to be clear, the model is correctly telling you that at a high protein value, the response is likely to be less "sick".  ... This is obviously not a great model for this case, as it's the medium protein values that tend to coincide with "very sick".

Comment: @Henry , this isn't the issue.  You can change the `sd`'s in the code to 10, so that there's overlap, and the overall result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

> Why?

To extend on the comment by @sal-mangiafico

This is because an inadvertent negative trend was introduced.  this is easiest to see in this replication with graph below:

```
set.seed(11112022)

d=data.frame(
  group=rep(c('control','sick','very_sick'),times=c(205,205,205)),
  protein=c(rnorm(205, mean=10, sd=1), rnorm(205, mean=-5, sd=1), rnorm(205, mean=5, sd=1)))

d$group <- factor(d$group,levels = c('control','sick','very_sick'), ordered = TRUE) 

d$group2 <- as.numeric(d$group)

ggplot(d, aes(x=group, y=protein)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + stat_smooth(aes(x = group2), method = "lm")
```

Producing:

[image: box with lm]

Because the outcome is treated as ordinal, the line fit has a slope given the pattern of means that trend downward given the implied ordering of the levels.

There is no problem with the model applied in this case.  The issue is, most likely, an unexpected result from the way the data were generated.